# DPDK-based traffic generator Warp17

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, packets, dpdk

Trying to get warp17 work. I built and installed as per the documentation, however I can't make it to generate the traffic -- it looks that it doesn't send out *anything* at all, counters are 0.

My NIC is Intel 82599ES 10-Gigabit, which is well supported by dpdk-16.11.

I'd be glad if someone who was more successful then me could share his/her experience. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Intel 82599ES is supported by Warp17. All counters 0 could mean that you're not starting (or configuring the tests). I would suggest first trying a back to back setup, preferably without any DUTs in between and running some of the [Warp17 examples](https://github.com/Juniper/warp17/blob/dev/common/README.md#example-run) in order to avoid any config related issues.

There's also the [Warp17 mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/warp17) for troubleshooting issues that might appear.

Comment: How to run warp in not a back to back setup i.e I want to run warp such that client and server are two different machines on two different network ? 
Out of all the examples mentioned [https://github.com/Juniper/warp17/tree/dev/common/examples] here , i couldn't find any such example.

Comment: Just start an instance of warp17 on each machine with two different configs. For example you could take a back to back sample config supplied with warp17 and split it in two configs (one for each instance). Don't forget to rename the ethernet port in the second config to 0 as each instance assigns port IDs starting from 0.